# Dereferencing strings and HashMaps in Rust

Tags: hashmap, rust, dereference, borrowing

I'm trying to understand how HashMaps work in Rust and I have come up with this example.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut roman2number: HashMap<&'static str, i32> = HashMap::new();
    roman2number.insert("X", 10);
    roman2number.insert("I", 1);

    let roman_num = "XXI".to_string();
    let r0 = roman_num.chars().take(1).collect::<String>();
    let r1: &str = &r0.to_string();
    println!("{:?}", roman2number.get(r1)); // This works

    // println!("{:?}", roman2number.get(&r0.to_string())); // This doesn't
}
```

When I try to compile the code with last line uncommented, I get the following error

```
error: the trait bound `&str: std::borrow::Borrow<std::string::String>` is not satisfied [E0277]
println!("{:?}", roman2number.get(&r0.to_string()));
                                            ^~~
note: in this expansion of format_args!
note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
```

The Trait implementation section of the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html) gives the dereferencing as `fn deref(&self) -> &str`

So what is happening here?

Comment: I think it's wrong (of whomever authored `HashMap::get`) to use the `Borrow` trait here. Basically the generic bound says: you can pass a reference to any type to `get`, if the key-type is borrowable as that type. It should actually be: you can pass any type to `get`, as long as that type is coercible to the key-type. But we can't fix this backwards compatibly :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error is caused by that generic function [`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) over `String` is selected by the compiler during type inference. But you want `HashMap::get` over `str`.

So just change

```
println!("{:?}", roman2number.get(&r0.to_string()));
```

to

```
println!("{:?}", roman2number.get::<str>(&r0.to_string()));
```

to make it explicit. This helps the compiler to select the right function.

Check out [Playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a314cb9b865007033499d8ff5e88f102&version=stable&backtrace=0).

It looks to me that coercion `Deref<Target>` can only happen when we know the target type, so when compiler is trying to infer which `HashMap::get` to use, it sees `&r0.to_string()` as type `&String` but never `&str`. And `&'static str` does not implement `Borrow<String>`. This results a type error. When we specify `HashMap::get::<str>`, this function expects `&str`, when coercion can be applied to `&String` to get a matching `&str`.

You can check out [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/deref-coercions.html) and [`String` Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/string/struct.String.html#deref) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. However, wouldn't it mean that Dref has two implementations? One returning &str and other &String? The document doesn't say anything about &String. Am I missing something here?

Comment: [`String` only implements `Deref<Target=str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/string/struct.String.html#deref). This implementation makes it possible to coerce `&String` into `&str` where `$str` is expected. See [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/deref-coercions.html).

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are correct, but I wanted to point out that you have an unneeded `to_string` (you've already `collect`ed into a `String`) and an alternate way of coercing to a `&str`, using `as`:

```
let r0: String = roman_num.chars().take(1).collect();
println!("{:?}", roman2number.get(&r0 as &str));
```

In *this* case, I'd probably just rewrite the map to contain `char` as the key though:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut roman2number = HashMap::new();
    roman2number.insert('X', 10);
    roman2number.insert('I', 1);

    let roman_num = "XXI";
    for c in roman_num.chars() {
        println!("{:?}", roman2number.get(&c));
    }
}
```

Note there's no need to have an explicit type for the map, it will be inferred.

Comment: And just to add another, equivalent alternative: `println!("{:?}", roman2number.get(r0.as_str()));`, the new-ish [`::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str) method.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of the `get` method looks as follows

```
fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V> where K: Borrow<Q>, Q: Hash + Eq
```

The first part is the type of object which you pass: `Q`. There are constraints on `Q`. The conditions on `Q` are that

1. the key-type `K` needs to implement the [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait over `Q`
2. `Q` needs to implement the `Hash` and `Eq` traits.

Replacing this with your actual types means that the key-type `&'static str` needs to implement `Borrow<String>`. By the definition of `Borrow`, this means that a `&'static str` needs to be convertible to `&String`. But all the docs/texts I've read state that everywhere you'd use `&String` you should be using `&str` instead. So it makes little sense to offer a `&str` -> `&String` conversion, even if it would make life a little easier sometimes.

Since every [reference type is borrowable as a shorter lived reference type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/up/src/libcore/borrow.rs.html#97-99).), you can pass a `&str` when a `&'static str` is the key-type, because `&'static str` implements `Borrow<str>`

Comment: Thank you. The explanation on Borrow makes sense!